# Mergesort recursive version intutition behind

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I have found the following part of a program of mergesort in a book:

```
def sort(v):
    if len(v)<=1:
       return v
    mid=len(v)//2
    v1,v2=sort(v[:mid]),sort(v[mid:])
    return merge(v1,v2)
```

The part of merge what it does is to compare each element of v1 and v2 and make a swap between them if its necessary. The question that I have is in relation with the sort() function. For example, if I pass a list like: [5,2,4,8,6,3]. It will get divided in chunks, call the sort() function recursively, but I do not find at which point does it call  the merge() function. So, is it fine if I suppose that the set of calls performed, for the lower half, is like this:

```
sort([5,4,2])=v1        sort([8,6,3])=v2

(at this point is called merge(v1,v2) or does it wait to the list to be exhausted?)

sort([5])=v1 sort ([4,2])=v2

(because the length of v1 is less than 1 then returns v which is [5], in this part I do not know how it gets joined with v2)

v[5]     sort(v[4])=v1  sort(v[2]))
(v[5] has been returned and the right part gets ordered so we will have v=[2,4])
```

In the last part I just do not know if I should call merge with v[5] and with v=[2,4] to make the ordering, is it like that? or am I missing something?

How can I correctly interpret this source code?

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate how mergesort works, I present my own implementation I wrote a while back:

```
def mergesort(lst):
    # SORT PART ------------------------------------------------
    # base case: return just this list if length = 1
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    # recursive case: do mergesort() on either half of the list
    mid = len(lst) // 2
    sub1, sub2 = mergesort(lst[:mid]), mergesort(lst[mid:])

    # MERGE PART ------------------------------------------------
    # merge sub1 and sub2, which are each sorted
    sorted_lst = []
    while sub1 and sub2:  # ...are not empty...
        # remove the lesser element from the front of sub1 or sub2 and add it to sorted list
        sorted_lst.append(sub1.pop(0) if sub1[0] < sub2[0] else sub2.pop(0))
    # finally, once one of the lists are empty, append the remainder of the other list.
    sorted_lst += (sub1 if sub1 else sub2)
    # and return the now-sorted list
    return sorted_lst
```

Essentially, mergesort splits the list in half, repeatedly, until it gets to singleton lists. At which point it puts the lower element before the higher element and returns that.

Then, the next level up considers the two lists it got back, and treats them both as priority queues - removes the lowest element between them, then the next-lowest element between them, etc. Said lowest element is always at the front, because the lower recursive layers made it that way.

Comment: thanks, but I would like to find how the implementation that I found works

Comment: @Little You'll notice that, besides variable names, my implementation is nearly identical. And also includes the merge part.

Comment: For example in your version, when does your code reaches the while sub1 and sub2? is it reached after the list is exhausted because it has been divided in chunks? or the while part is reached in every recursive call?

Comment: @Little It's *eventually* reached in every recursive call except the last one (which hits the base case), but in the opposite order. `[1]` and `[2]` will be merged together, `[3]` and `[4]` will be merged together, and then the parent call will merge `[1, 2]` and `[3, 4]` together, and then the parent of *that* will merge `[1, 2, 3, 4]` with whatever the other recursive call was that it started, and so on. When you recurse, you don't *exit* the function - you *come back to it later* after doing it with different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In a top down merge sort, merging does not begin until two base cases where sub-array size has been reduced to a single element occurs. After that the merging and splitting continue up and down the call chain, depth first and usually left first.

With the questions example code, recursion will repeatedly follow the left path of sort(v[:mid]) until a base case one element is reached before that instance returns to allow the second call sort(v[mid:]), which could be two elements in which case one more level of recursion occurs and then merging begins.